# how to split lines into an array based on criteria using perl?

Tags: perl

how to split lines into an array based on criteria using perl?

I have the following file with delimiter of space between each paragraph..

logInformation.txt

```
               LogA
                    fjlfjdklafjdkla;fdjklafdja
                    adjalfdlafdjkla;fdla;fdl;a
                    faklfdaldflkafdlkafdklafdl
              LogB
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd
              LogC
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd


               LogA
                    fjlfjdklafjdkla;fdjklafdja
                    adjalfdlafdjkla;fdla;fdl;a
                    faklfdaldflkafdlkafdklafdl
              LogB
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd
              LogC
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd


               LogA
                    fjlfjdklafjdkla;fdjklafdja
                    adjalfdlafdjkla;fdla;fdl;a
                    faklfdaldflkafdlkafdklafdl
              LogB
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd
              LogC
                    djfkalfjdklafdkla;fdkla;fd
                    afdjkalfdkla;fdlk;afdla;fd
```

Using perl, how do I only get LogB information

Comment: How can you make the difference beetween 'LogB' and the other lines ('djka....') ? Can we assume that there is a fixed (and given) number of space before each type of lines ? Or that 'labels' will have less than 5 chars, and the 'datas' more than 5 ?

Comment: the delimiter between each log record is a newline

Comment: It was not what I was asking, but you've got an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $LogB = 0;
while (<>) {
    $LogB = 1 if /^\s*LogB\b/;        # set flag if line is LogB
    $LogB = 0 if /^\s*Log[^B]\b/;     # clear flag if some other log starts here
    print $_ if $LogB;                # print out LogB, and its entries
}
```

to create a list while also trimming the leading whitespace and getting rid of `LogB`s:

```
my ($LogB, @data);
while (<>) {chomp;
    $LogB = 1 if /^\s*LogB\b/;
    $LogB = 0 if /^\s*Log[^B]\b/;
    $_ =~ s/^\s*(?:\bLogB\b)?\s*//;
    push(@data, $_) if $LogB and $_; 
}
print join("\n", @data), "\n";
```

Comment: I know that this works, but could you please explain what exactly is going on here? I see what you're doing with `$LogB`, as in I understand what it means for `$logB` to be 0 or 1; however, I don't understand how you're actually searching through the text.  The regex makes sense, but where are you actually comparing it against input?

Comment: By using `if /regex/` does perl automatically compare it to `$_` if there nothing else to explicitly compare it to?

Comment: yes, it operates on `$_` (context variable I guess) if you don't specify anything